# Comprobar si un String contiene un caracter de otro String

Tags: java

Tengo un String que almacena una contraseña y quiero comprobar si es segura, poco segura, etc...
Los criterios son que para ser muy segura debe tener minimo un numero, una letra Mayus y una letra minus, un caracter especial y minimo 8 caracteres.

Para hacer la comprobacion de caracteres quiero hacerlo con varios String que almacenen todos los posibles caracteres

Ejemplo

```
String minus = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String mayus = letrasMinus.toUpperCase();
String num= "1234567890";
String especial = "=!\"·$%&/()";
```

Y de estos String verificar que el String que almacena la contraseña contenga alguno de esos caracteres para determinar su seguridad

Lo intenté con contains pero no me funciona
Esta es la condicion que usé:

```
String c = "AabbcD12$";  //Deberia decir que es muy segura
if(c.length() >= 8 && c.contains(minus) && c.contains(mayus) && c.contains(num) && c.contains(especial)) {
System.out.println("La contraseña es muy segura");
} else {
System.out.println("Otro tipo");
}
```

Con esta condicion pasa a "Otro tipo" directamente

Gracias de antemano

Comment: nota: c.contains(minus) ahi dice.. c contiene minus??? pero minus, es un string que tiene muchos caracteres.. o sea, le estas preguntando a c si contiene todo minus.. no un caracter en particular....

Comment: Claro esa es mi duda, como hago para decirle que busque solo un caracter de esa cadena... hay alguna forma sin necesidad de usar for o charAt?

Comment: Lo intenté con matches pero tampoco funciono... entonces no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo... mi objetivo es la menor cantidad de lineas posibles con la mayor eficiencia... y si empiezo a poner for por todos lados ensucio el codigo

Comment: Que te hace pensar que cualquier funcion que uses, no va a tener que hacer un for y sacar caracter por caracter para hacer la comprobacion? si no lo queres escribir vos, ok.. pero siempre vas a tener ciclos ahi....

Comment: Entonces no hay ninguna forma de hacerlo sin usar for?

Comment: tu pregunta es sin que vos escribas un for, por mas que se encuentre una funcion que si lo haga internamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando regex puedes simplificar lo que necesitas,es lo que mas se usa para contraseñas o cifrado

Al menos una mayúscula  (?=.*?[A-Z])

Al menos una letra minúscula  (?=.*?[a-z])

Al menos un numero (?=.*?[0-9])

Al menos un carácter especial (?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])

Mínimo ocho caracteres {8,}

```
public static String validarPassword(String password){
        String pass;
        Pattern pat= Pattern.compile("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(password);

        if(mat.matches()){
           pass="Muy Segura";
        }else{
          pass="No tan Segura";
        }  
        return pass;                                                                         

    }
```

Comment: Ya veo... tiene sentido usar las expresiones regulares... gracias

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo.
package com.mkyong.regex.password;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PasswordValidator {

```
// digit + lowercase char + uppercase char + punctuation + symbol
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN =
        "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*~$^+=<>]).{8,20}$";

private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);

public static boolean isValid(final String password) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```